# Async/await в DataLayer - потерял преимущества

Tags: c#

В небольшом приложении получаю данные из SQL во ViewModel напрямую через `SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync()` и `SqlDataReader.ReadAsync()`. Полученная коллекция `Collection<T>` отображается в `DataGrid`. Запрос не быстрый, но такая связка позволяет не блокировать UI, и `DataGrid` заполняется по мере поступления данных из SQL, что хорошо.

Решил перенести запрос в DataLayer, создал async-метод `GetCollectionAsync()`. UI по прежнему не блокируется, но теперь DataGrid заполняется только после получения **всей** коллекции. Получается, что я выиграл от разделения кода на уровни, но проиграл в функциональности. Что я делаю не так?

Было:

```
public class ViewModel
{
        public ICollection<Order> colOrders;

        public async void GetDataAsync()
        {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnect = new qlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Id, Customer from Orders", sqlConnect);

            sqlConnect.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    colOrders.Add(new Order(reader["Id"], reader["Customer"]));
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Стало:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ICollection<Order> colOrders;

    protected async void GetDataAsync() {
        DataLayer dl = new DataLayer();
        colOrders = await dl.GetDataAsync();
    }
}
```

Код в `Task<ICollection<Order>>DataLayer.GetDataAsync()` делает всё то же самое, что и предыдущий.
Всякие try...catch для простоты опускаю.

Comment: добавь пример кода

Comment: а причем тут `async\await`?

Answer (score 1):

Можете сделать примерно так. С обычными `IEnumerable` будет сложно, а здесь вы просто подписываетесь на событие, которое запускается при добавлении новых записей:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    collection.CollectionChanged += (s, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            foreach (string value in args.NewItems)
                listbox.Items.Add(value);
    };
    await GetData(collection);
}

private async Task GetData(ObservableCollection<string> collection)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        collection.Add("Item-" + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел устраивающий меня вариант решения (спасибо Zergatul, натолкнул на идею).

Вместо

```
protected async void GetDataAsync() {
    DataLayer dl = new DataLayer();
    colOrders = await dl.GetDataAsync();
}
```

стал передавать коллекцию как параметр в DataLayer, а выход поменял на bool. Получилось:

```
protected async void GetDataAsync() {
    DataLayer dl = new DataLayer();
    bool isOK = await dl.FillDataAsync(colOrders);
}
```

UI не блокируется, коллекция к моменту вызова `DataLayer` у меня уже есть, данные вываливаются в `DataGrid` порциями - всё как я хотел.